# Add File/personal Geodatabse to Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, file-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase

Is it possible to add file or personal geodatabase to Geoserver?
If not, how we can get rid of shapefile limitations in Geoserver (without using a database like PostGIS)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *might* be possible using the [OGR Datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/ogr.html) though I'm not sure if that is supported (or even tested) with GeoServer. Though you will need to make sure that you have the requisite dlls installed and OGR compiled to make use of them and with Java support built in. I suspect this will be a custom compile but as I don't use windows or ESRI formats I can't say I've checked.

For a good standard format you would be well advised to consider [GeoPackages](http://www.geopackage.org/spec/). GeoServer has a [community module](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/geopkg/index.html) that can read them as datastores and write them as WMS and WFS outputs. QGIS can handle them natively too.

Comment: Just wanted to answer the same like the second part. Consider switching from proprietary ESRI formats to OGC Geopackage.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was thinking about something like first solution but i didn't find good tutorials about it on the internet. Now, i'm gonna test 2nd soultion. But meanwhile, does Geopackage support non-english characters in field names?